# delphi x32 and x64, (typecast?) array of bytes into (wide)string

Tags: arrays, delphi

I receive from an external function(dll) widestring in array of bytes.

to convert the bytes to string, I use the following simple code:

```
mystrvar := widestring(buffer);
```

where buffer is the byte array.

when compile for 32bits, it works great, but when compile this for 64bits code returns empty string while the buffer(byte array) is the same in both cases.

the same happens when use
    mystrvar := string(buffer);
while pchar(buffer) or pwchar(buffer) works.

Reason why I do not use pwchar is;
pwchar(buffer) breaks by  00 while widestring(buffer) does not. This buffer(bytearray) contains stringlist which is delimited by (00).

btw, excuse me for bad english.

Comment: Oh, come on, you keep asking for trouble. There is `SetString` for that.

Comment: setstring breaks allso by #0 when compile 64 bit. I can use another construction like read the buffer byte by byte. But the strange thing is why widestring(buffer) behaves different in 32 and 64 bit compiling.

Comment: @coban: `SetString()` **does not** break on #0 characters. It does not even look at the characters, it is a straight memory copy using whatever input length you specify. If you are having problems with #0 characters then you are doing something wrong. Please show your real code.

Comment: No, `SetString` does not.

Comment: I think it was a mis usage of code, indeed setstring does not break on #0.

Comment: As u can see I am not a skilled (Delphi) programmer, my knowledge is based on about 16 years ago, trying to increase my programming skills and refreshing the knowledge.
I don't remember how I did but yesterday somehow I got a #0 broken result using setstring, today it is not breaking and putting complete buffer array( bytes) into the string variable.

Comment: Your typecast is wrong everywhere I think. WideString is the COM string. You want `string`, an alias to `UnicodeString`. It's essentially an array of 16 bit character elements. Why do you have a byte array? How is it encoded?

Comment: I get a result from an winapi function call, setupapi, in byte array of variable length. To be specific, the function is; SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW from setupapi.dll which can return different result types like boolean, string, etc. 
I don't know why but somehow when this function returns result of type stringlist, the stringlist is delimited by #0.

Comment: The api is documented. It's double null terminated UTF-16 data is it? Can't you parse that?

Comment: I was allready finished the app, but I was planning to add extra functionality to backup the driver files and I got stuck by a function, "SetupDiCallClassInstaller", which failed. After some googling, found out that the function was failing when it is being called from a 32bit application.
For that reason I recompiled the application to 64bits and got some errors. One of them was this one, now thanks to u I know that I was using wrong code to convert the byte array to string.

there is still no answer why widestring(buffer) behaves different on 32 and 64 bit compiling.

Comment: SetupDiCallClassInstaller fails because I am calling it on a 64bit machine from a 32 bit application. There is whole explanation why it fails but that is not the current discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
SetString(mystrvar,buffer,LENGTH(buffer) DIV SizeOf(WideChar));
```

assuming that

```
VAR
  mystrvar : WideString;
  buffer: ARRAY OF BYTE;
```

and that "buffer" does not contain a trailing zero-terminating set of bytes. Also note that "buffer" is an array of BYTEs and thus the length of the buffer is twice that of the length of the resulting string.

Comment: isn't it setstring(mystrvar, pwchar(buffer), length(buffer) );

And is it necessary to divide the length of buffer by sizeof widechar, what if  i do not divide ?

Comment: @Heartware You probably should mention the encoding. The assumption here is that the byte array contains UTF16LE.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Isn't WideString always UniCode (16-bit) LE on Windows? If it works with a simple type cast in 32-bit then there should be no difference with respect to byte order for 64-bit.

Comment: @coban: If you don't divide, then the string will contains 16 characters for an array of 16 bytes (the third parameter is the _length_ - in characters - of the string), but since it is a WideString, a character consists of 2 bytes each, and thus the _length_ of the string is 8 characters, but the _size_ of the string is 16 bytes.

Comment: I tried this with and without dividing,  until now I got the same result, but I think this is because I never got sepcial chars from the external function call. Because my result is coming from setupapi.dll maybe I should try this on a machine with another language installed which contains more "special" characters like (Ç, Ö) etc.
As I told before the app I am building is for my own "educational" purpose to improve my programming knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your array is double Null Terminating you can use this:

```
while Buffer^ <> WideNull do
begin
  value := PWChar(Buffer);
  CommaText := CommaText + value + ',';
  Inc(Buffer, (Length(value) + 1)); 
end;
```